# MVC 4 Redirect to external Page from controller

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an existing Web Site that uses multiple ASP .Net Web Forms projects. I have created an MVC 4 mobile web application to replace the login/ authorization web form project.

So far I have been able to replace all the functionality of the site, except I am unable to redirect to the ASP .Net pages from inside the Controller.

Using this method I can reach other MVC applications on the same web site without issue:

```
return Redirect("MyURLstring");
```

However when I redirect to a Web Forms page I receive several JS errors, and the Page never redirects. It looks like the MVC application is attempting to apply JQuery 1.7.1 to the URL that is being opened.

I can reach the URL without error if I include a rel="external" tag within a hyperlink in a view.

I have also attempted to solve this by creating a route in my RouteConfig.cs file

```
RouteValueDictionary RouteValues = new RouteValueDictionary();
RouteValues["rel"] = "external";
return RedirectToRoute("MyRouteName", RouteValues);
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you're getting JS errors then it has nothing to do with ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: Thanks for the weigh in. However, I'm looking for any feedback on what I may be missing so that I can redirect to a URL from within a controller while using rel="external". If I follow the URL using a standard hyperlink with the rel="external" anchor tag, then it works without issue. The only way I get an error is if I am try to access the URL through the MVC controller redirect methods.

Comment: I solved this problem by removing the view reference to: ~/bundles/jquerymobile in Layout.cshtml, but preserving it in Layout.Mobile.cshtml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

I created the project as a MVC 4 Mobile site as a base, but still had the referencing to jQuery Mobile in my main _Layout view.

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery", "~/bundles/jquerymobile", "~/bundles/jquerycustom")
```

I kept this code intact for my _Layout.Mobile.cstml view, but changed to below for _Layout.cshtml

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery", "~/bundles/jquerycustom")
```

This allows me to perform a return Redirect("myURL"); from the controller without hopping through all the jQuery that was preventing the redirect.